# Firebase: Provided bucket does not match the Storage bucket of the current instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage().reference(forURL: "gs://slugbug-....appspot.com") // dots intentional
let imageRef = storageRef.child("testImage.jpg")
```

But the app crashes and I get the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Provided bucket:
>   slugbug-....appspot.com does not match the Storage bucket of the
>   current instance: (null)'

Even if I use

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage().reference()
```

The bucket is nil.

Why?

Comment: Accept answer please, to let others to find it faster. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

I changed the code from:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage().reference(forURL: "gs://slugbug-....appspot.com")
```

to:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://slugbug-....appspot.com")
```

... a very subtle but annoying bug

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `.storage()`.

Check your line. It should be:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://slugbug-....appspot.com") // dots intentional
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use below code work

```
 // call storage ref from link
 self.storageRef =  FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "your_URL")

     // Assuming your image size < 10MB.
     self.storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
           if data != nil{ // if image found 
              let photo = UIImage(data: data!)
                  // User photo here
               }
     })
```