# firebase / storage / image / view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I am developing a project in swift 4 and among other functions I need to show images that are in my firebase / storage.

but I've tried it anyway and I can not find the right codes.

if anyone knows and wants to help this beginner would be very grateful.

thanks

Comment: Try this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253124/firebase-storage-bucket-issue-ios-swift/44253466#44253466

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image URL using below code snippet:

Objective-C code snippet:

```
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage] reference];
   FIRStorageReference *groupsRef = [storageRef child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/%@",@"Group",@"imageName"]];
    [groupsRef downloadURLWithCompletion:^(NSURL * _Nullable URL, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    }];
```

Once you receive the URL use any Image downloading framework or NSUrlSession to download image and show in UIImageView.

Recommended image downloader: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Hope this will help to resolve your above issue. Convert this Objective-C code to Swift as per your requirement.